# Sort List by string converted to int

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a list of Int saved as String and I would like to order them. 
I came up with the following solution:

```
sortList = sortList.OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Number)).ToList();
```

It works perfectly, but only if the list **only** contains numbers. For example, if there is one item that is a string like "???" the sorting totally fails.

Expectation:

```
['313', '309', '119', '49', '???']
```

Result:

```
['309' '49' '313' '119' '???']
```

Comment: What is `x.Number`?

Comment: x.Number is the String in the object.

Comment: Your output shows something like strings, but strings don't have `Number` property. If you have objects, then output should look like `[{Number:"309"},{Number:"49"}...]`

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I think he is saying that the second list is what he actually gets (ie the bad result), rather than what he wants which is the first list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you need to use [`int.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) and return a low value for invalid strings:

```
sortList = sortList.OrderByDescending(x =>
    {
        int i;
        return int.TryParse(x.Number, out i) ? i : int.MinValue;
    });
```

I use `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy` as the expected result you showed is in descending order.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin his expectation is orderd descending,

Answer (score 4):

In [C# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7), you can reduce this to just a single line, while still using `TryParse()` by using [`out`-variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7#out-variables):

```
sortList = sortList.OrderBy(x => Int32.TryParse(x.Number, out var i) ? i : Int32.MinValue).ToList();
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere: but you don't need to declare them anymore. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7#out-variables A great improvement, because currently you need to modify (local)  variables in LINQ queries which is considereed  bad practise

Answer (score -1):

Sort input list of any type (ex. PROP01) selecting the property to convert (ex. XSTRING1_FIELD). Return input list sorted.

```
    private static List<PROP01> _getListPROP01OrderedByXSTRING1_FIELD(List<PROP01> iList)
    {
        // INIT
        List<PROP01> retObj = new List<PROP01>();
        int tempKey = 0;
        int jj = 0;
        // GET 
        SortedList<int, PROP01> tempSorted = new SortedList<int, PROP01>();

        foreach (var currObj in iList)
        {                
            try {
                tempKey = Convert.ToInt32(currObj.XSTRING1_FIELD);
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                tempKey = (Int32.MaxValue - jj);
                ++jj;
            }
            tempSorted.Add(tempKey, currObj);
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, PROP01> currObj in tempSorted)
        {
            // retObj.Add(currObj.Value);  // ascending order
            retObj.Insert(0, currObj);     // descending order
        }
        // RET
        return retObj;
    }
```

Comment: This is far more contrived code than the already given answers *and* it is wrong because it'll throw an exception. Also: use code from the question to post answers, not your own code, it hampers the interpretation.

Comment: Maybe you just haven't understood what a "SortedList" does, or maybe you do not understand a static method that changes the input list to a sorted input list.. about exception they are not errors, are evidence of strange input like this: '???'

Comment: Try to focus on what I said instead of immediately assuming anything when someone doesn't agree with you. Your code doesn't allow input `"???"` while it should. `TryParse` is required. The existing answers were sufficient.

Comment: Going from bad to worse. Just look at your code now and try to imagine someone else wrote it. And now try to flip ascending/descending.